# Did Trump's administration indicate their opinion of whitehouse.gov petitions?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, petition

Leaving aside the specific politics of their answers, my overall impression was that Obama administration treated [Whitehouse petitions](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/) more like a minor sideshow than anything else. Writing less than committal responses to ones that legally required a response, but not really using them as a tool of governance. Just to be clear, that's my personal impression and may not be supported by actual reality of what went on in the administration.

Did Donald Trump's administration **indicate their opinion of whitehouse.gov petitions**? Do they plan to take them seriously as input or indicator of public mood? Ignore? Aren't even aware of that thing?

Comment: The first test will be with the whitehouse.gov petitions. Following the Obama tradition, the site says a response will be given within 60 days to any petition that gets 100,000 signatures within 30 days. The first petition created on January 20 (Inauguration Day) asks for the immediate release of Trump's tax returns. It currently has over 546,000 signatures.

Comment: @jalynn2 - I was under impression these two are the same thing actually. If not, whitehouse.gov (the one with SLA and rules) is the one I was meaning to ask about. Let me fix.

Comment: @Walmart - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c

Comment: Can you include any research you did before asking?

Comment: I'm not sure the comparison to Obama in the question is necessary; just asking about the Trump adminstration's intention would be enough. If the comparison should stay, it may be fairer to compare apples to apples here (ie Trump's intention vs Obama's intention or reality vs reality). My guess is it's probably the same for both (*if* they said something about petitions, it's probably positive, but it probably will not have major influences on the policies of either).

Comment: @tim - more an explanation of why I cared about the topic in the first place (see all SE questions about Obama era petitions). Feel free to edit out Obama, it's not very pertinenty other than that reason.

Answer (score 3):

The White House has resumed responding to petitions after the site [was restored](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/372176-white-house-re-launches-petition-site), following the revamp of the White House website.

[Some of the petitions](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/responses#petitionswithupdates) were answered, including

- one calling for the [release of Donald Trump's full tax returns](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/immediately-release-donald-trumps-full-tax-returns-all-information-needed-verify-emoluments-clause-compliance) and;
- another one calling for the [preservation of the National Endowment for the Arts (NEA) and the National Endowment for the Humanities (NEH)](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/preserve-national-endowment-arts-and-national-endowment-humanities).

No concrete action has been taken on any petitions so far.

Comment: Am I the only one who feels that the response to the first one was copy/pasted from Stack Exchange stock comment? :)

Comment: ... and the response to the second one is basically a stock Stack Exchange team's response on main Meta?